# My audio isn't working after plugging in headphones

Tags: audio, windows-10, speakers

I plugged my headphones into my computer, and after I unplugged them, my laptop speakers are no longer working. I tried to plug the headphones back in thinking that maybe the switch in the headphone jack was stuck, but the headphones weren't working either then.

When I play audio (youtube, pandora, etc), and the playback tab under sound shows that there is audio going through to the communication headphones even though speakers/headphones is set to default.

When I try to play a test sound, it said "failed to play test tone"

Answer (score 0):

The *Sound* Control Panel application has settings for both *Default Device* and *Default Communications Device*. Try setting the *Speakers* to both by right-clicking the icon. After selecting it, that context-menu item is no longer shown for that device.

You might need to set *another* device as defaults , e.g. *Headphones*, and then revert to *Speakers*, to force the settings to be retained.

Your thought about the headphone-jack switch being faulty is reasonable, though.

[image: Windows Sound CPL]